# In an iOS 5 Storyboard with a Split View Controller, how do you push a new View Controller to the Master and Detail from the same control?

Tags: ios, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller, ios5, storyboard

When I click a control, I want it to push a new view controller to both the Master Split and the Detail Split.

Unfortunately, in the Storyboard editor, when you control drag from an object and create a segue to a View Controller, it overwrites the original value of the `Push Storyboard Segue` field.

Is it possible to accomplish my goal in the storyboard file, or does it have to be done in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably have to override `-[UIViewController prepareForSegue:sender:]` and do the extra push yourself; storyboards are designed to manage the navigation flow for a single view controller at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be much nicer and cleaner if you would just Control+drag, but don't leave the segue with a default, "Push" style. Notice that there is also "Replace" style available for segues here. When you choose "Replace" style, there will be "Destination" parameter available. Choose whether you want to replace a view in Master, or Details controller, and that's it.

Comment: Hey Eedoh, the question was how to push two different view controllers at the same time: replacing both the master and detail view controllers from the same segue/control.